# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python

i am getting a TypeError with the following code:

```
def date_check(datetocheck):
    import datetime
    if datetocheck.date < datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=20):
        print("Go")


def date():
    from datetime import datetime
    # datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime('09.02.19 14:03:34', '%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S')

    date_check(datetime_object)


date()
```

And i don't get why, both objects are from the datime modul.

Changed:
datetocheck.date -> datetocheck.date()

Now getting this error:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Comment: `datetocheck.date` -> `datetocheck.date()`

Comment: Now i am getting this error: TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Comment: `datetocheck.date()` -> `datetocheck`

Comment: There we go, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Remove .date in datetocheck.date() altogether**, and it should work.

This is because datetocheck.date() only contains the date info: datetime.date(2019, 2, 9), and you can't compare that with the date & time info, that you get from datetime.datetime.now().